# Get index of row in table by condition in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I have a question regarding iterating through tables in webdriver.
I want to get the current index of row that contains cell with conditional link.
But the result is always the index of first row of table instead of expected row. 
The test method is listed below.

```
public boolean viewDetailsOfOccasion(String occasionDate) { 
WebElement ocassionsTable = (new WebDriverWait(Driver.getDriver(), 5)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.tagName("table")));
    List<WebElement> tableRows = ocassionsTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
        for (int i = 0; i < tableRows.size(); i++) {
            List<WebElement> tableCols = tableRows.get(i).findElements(By.xpath("//td/div/a"));
                for (int j = 0; j < tableCols.size(); j++) {
                if (tableCols.get(j).getText().equals(occasionDate)) { 
                        System.out.println(i);
                        return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
        return false;
    }
```

What is wrong in this implementation?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've forgot about the brackets, because inner loop will be ended after the first run (`return true`):

```
for (int j = 0; j < tableCols.size(); j++) {
    if (tableCols.get(j).getText().equals(occasionDate)) {
        System.out.println(i);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I missed bracket during copy paste of code, it is just my inaccuracy. But the question is still open.

Comment: @yuravigor that just means that condition `tableCols.get(j).getText().equals(occasionDate)` is true for the 1st column in 1st row, because `return` breaks all outer loops.

Comment: I have changed return type of method to void, and I have got indexes of all rows in table. How can I get the index of certain row that contains cell with needed text?

Comment: @yuravigor have you checked via debugger if your condition is `true` for every word or not?

Comment: the problem was in usage of xpath locator (//td/div/a) to find  links in table cells. I just have replaced xpath to css, and the result was the same as expected.